# Missing Dependency: perl(YAML::Any)

Tags: centos5, git, yum

I have a problem with git, when I run yum upgrade on a centos5 server.

```
yum upgrade
```

output:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package perl-Git.x86_64 0:1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Ra) for package: perl-Git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Delta) for package: perl-Git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Client) for package: perl-Git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML::Any) for package: perl-Git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(SVN::Core) for package: perl-Git
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-Git.x86_64 0:1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML::Any) for package: perl-Git
---> Package subversion-perl.x86_64 0:1.6.11-10.el5_8 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: subversion = 1.6.11-10.el5_8 for package: subversion-perl
--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_wc-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-perl
--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_fs-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-perl
--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_diff-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-perl
--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_subr-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-perl
--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_delta-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-perl
--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_repos-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-perl
--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_ra-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-perl
--> Processing Dependency: libsvn_client-1.so.0()(64bit) for package: subversion-perl
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-Git.x86_64 0:1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML::Any) for package: perl-Git
---> Package subversion.x86_64 0:1.6.11-10.el5_8 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(YAML::Any) is needed by package perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(YAML::Any) is needed by package perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
```

When I try yum info perl-YAML, it says, that perl-YAML is installed.

```
Name       : perl-YAML
Arch       : noarch
Version    : 0.66
Release    : 2.el5.art
Size       : 171 k
Repo       : installed
```

Whats the problem here?

Thanks flo

Comment: Try running cpan -i YAML::Any and see if that helps

Comment: You are installing Git from rpmforge and it may require newer YAML. Try to install newest YAML from CPAN as Logic Wreck recommends.

Comment: I ran cpan -i YAML:Any, but I get this error also with the newest YAML files.

Comment: I'd also encountered this problem. Maybe it's related to other packages/repos installed on the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this one:

http://pkgs.repoforge.org/perl-YAML/perl-YAML-0.72-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm

which worked for me:

```
# yum install git
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf for package: git
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-Git.x86_64 0:1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: perl(YAML::Any) for package: perl-Git
--> Running transaction check
---> Package perl-YAML.noarch 0:0.72-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package         Arch         Version                   Repository         Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 git             x86_64       1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf         third-party       8.2 M
Installing for dependencies:
 perl-Git        x86_64       1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf         third-party        56 k
 perl-YAML       noarch       0.72-1.el5.rf             third-party        84 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       3 Package(s)
Upgrade       0 Package(s)

Total download size: 8.3 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/3): perl-Git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm             |  56 kB     00:00
(2/3): perl-YAML-0.72-1.el5.rf.noarch.rpm                |  84 kB     00:00
(3/3): git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm                  | 8.2 MB     00:00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                            38 MB/s | 8.3 MB     00:00
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing     : perl-YAML                                                1/3
  Installing     : perl-Git                                                 2/3
  Installing     : git                                                      3/3

Installed:
  git.x86_64 0:1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf

Dependency Installed:
  perl-Git.x86_64 0:1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf      perl-YAML.noarch 0:0.72-1.el5.rf

Complete!
```